# Using Weka to Classify Author Blog Gender

Tags: java, excel, machine-learning, weka

I am trying to use Weka in Java to classify an author's blog as written by a male or female. I build a class called Weka which defines the attributes to be used in the training set and then calls a method to load all the already known data from an excel sheet. The data in the file is organized like this: each row has blog text in cell 0 and then an M or an F in cell 1.

blog text   M
more text   F

I am also following this tutorial a little [Weka Java Tutorial](http://ianma.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/weka-with-java-eclipse-getting-started/)

When I run the program I start to see text whizz by in the console window in eclipse but suddenly I get a red error that says "Value not defined for given nominal attribute!" I'm not quite sure why this happens. The text is changing from row to row so I thought it was not possible to define all the nominal attributes. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or stupid here??? I would greatly appreciate any help. I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours.

CODE:

```
    public class Weka
{
    static FastVector fvWekaAttributes;
    static Instances isTrainingSet;
    static Classifier cModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {



        // Declaring attributes
        Attribute stringAttribute = new Attribute("text", (FastVector) null);

        // Declaring a class attribute along with values
        FastVector fastVClassVal = new FastVector(2);
        fastVClassVal.addElement("M");
        fastVClassVal.addElement("F");

        Attribute classAttribute = new Attribute("theClass", fastVClassVal);

        // Declaring the feature vector
        fvWekaAttributes = new FastVector(2);
        fvWekaAttributes.addElement(stringAttribute);
        fvWekaAttributes.addElement(classAttribute);

        // create the training set
        isTrainingSet = new Instances("Rel", fvWekaAttributes, 10);

        // set class index
        isTrainingSet.setClassIndex(1);

        // create however many instances is in my excel file
        // and add it to the training set in a loop.
        Weka.LoadExcelWorkBook(isTrainingSet);
        Weka.TestSetWork();

    }

    public static void TestSetWork() throws Exception
    {
        // test the model
        Evaluation testing = new Evaluation(isTrainingSet);
        testing.evaluateModel(cModel, isTrainingSet);

        // printing the results....
        String strSummary = testing.toSummaryString();
        System.out.println(strSummary);

        // get confusion matrix.

        double[][] cmMatrix = testing.confusionMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < cmMatrix.length; i++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < cmMatrix.length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(cmMatrix[i][col]);
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void LoadExcelWorkBook(Instances trainingSet)
            throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("LOADING EXCEL WORKBOOK!!!");
        Workbook wb = null;
        // opening excel file.

        try
        {
            wb = WorkbookFactory
                    .create(new File("C://blog-gender-dataset.xlsx"));

        } catch (IOException ieo)
        {
            ieo.printStackTrace();
        }

        // opening worksheet.
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
        filter.setInputFormat(isTrainingSet);

        Instances dataFiltered = Filter.useFilter(isTrainingSet, filter);

        for (Row row : sheet)
        {

            Cell textCell = row.getCell(0);
            Cell MFCell = row.getCell(1);

            String blogText = textCell.getStringCellValue();
            String MFIndicator = MFCell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("TEXT FROM EXCEL " + blogText);
            Instance iText = new Instance(2);

            iText.setValue((Attribute) fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(0), tweetText);
            iText.setValue((Attribute) fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(1),
                    MFIndicator);

            isTrainingSet.add(iText);

            cModel = (Classifier) new J48();
            cModel.buildClassifier(dataFiltered);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why use excel to store data, instead of csv or arff?
Why write the read data code yourself, instead of using weka fileReader - ArffLoader.
I don't think you use blog text as one attribute is a good idea, try word segmentation first, and use the words as input attributes. And Before you feed your data into a classifier, you may want to do attribute selection first.

Comment: Using a CSV is not really a good option here sense the blog text itself contains commas. Unless the text has " " around it like it's supposed to. I already tried to save the excel as a CSV and open it in Weka and it ran into issues. What do you mean by attribute selection before feeding it to the classifier? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, attribute selection actually is feature selection. You should segment words in blog text, and use words as input attributes. Commas will not be a problem. Say your blog text is "This is an example, example.", after word segmentation you may got "this,is,an,example\n1,1,1,2\n" as csv content.

Comment: Yeah, last night I realized that I really needed to format my file better. So I am currently in the process of turning it into an ARFF type. So far everything is going good. I'd imagine once I complete it the program will be easier to write. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: If everything is ok, please set the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

"Value not defined for given nominal attribute!" arrives when in instances that you construct, expected data happen to have other values than the ones that you defined in the arff @attribute section for a given nominal attribute. 
For instance, you defined expected values to be "M" or "F" , but the values that you read could be empty(N/A), etc.
The solution is to rigurously verify your data, debug /trace what you load for that attribute on which the error occurs, and either add that value to the possible values for that attribute -- or, if this appears systematically in your case, define that attribute as having a more generic type (string, numeric,..).